# How to properly use a lambda expression with the scipy.derivative method?

Tags: python, function, lambda, scipy

I have written the following function to calculate the probability that a single reaction in a system of reaction fires and stores the output of the function, the probability of each reaction in the system firing, as an array:

```
def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
    propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
    for row in range(len(LHS)):
            a = stoch_rate[row]     
            for i in range(len(popul_num)):
                if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):       
                    binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                    a = a*binom_rxn
                else:
                    a = 0
                    break
            propensity[row] = a     
    return propensity
```

The inputs for this function are 3 arrays `popul_num` has the discrete number of molecules of each reactant, `LHS` is a 2D array with the ratios between each molecule species for each reaction in the system and `stoch_rate` is the rate of each reaction.

I now want to call the `propensity_calc` function with the scipy.misc.derivative method in a different function to calculate the partial derivative: bji(x) = daj(x)/xi, where aj(x) is the result from the above propensity_calc function and xi is the corresponding elements of the popul_num array.

This is what I've got written so far:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy import optimize

def time_step_calc(popul_num, state_change_array, a0):
    # equation 22:
    expctd_net_change = a0*state_change_array
    print("expected net change:\n", expctd_net_change)
    # equation 24 partial differentiation:
    for x in range(len(popul_num)):
        part_propensity_diff = derivative(lambda LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate: propensity_calc, popul_num[x])    <-- Error here with the number of arguments passed to lambda
    # equation 26:
    t_step = epsi*a0 / sum(expctd_net_change*part_propensity_diff)
    delta_t = optimize.fmin(t_step, 0.00012) 
    print("calculated delta_t:\n", delta_t)
    return delta_t
```

To pass the propensity_calc function to scipy.derviative I've tried to use a lambda function but I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line 119, in derivative
val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'popul_num' and 'stoch_rate'
```

I've read the lambda documentation but I still don't understand where I'm going wrong, any suggestions as to how I can fix this error and do the partial differentiation?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lambda` you defined is a constant function of three parameters that always return a function. Since you want a one-dimensional function (from my understanding), what you probably meant is:

```py
lambda popul_num: propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)
```

This can be read as "The function that takes a parameter called `popul_num` and returns `propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)`".

By calling `scipy.misc.derivative` with the above `lambda` at point `popul_num[x]`, you will get the value of the partial derivative of `propensity_calc` with respect to `popul_num` at point `(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)`. It means that you have to define `LHS` and `stoch_rate` in this case. Indeed, don't forget that the partial derivative is still a function of three parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what does the w.r.t shorthand stand for?

Comment: with respect to

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Scipy will only pass one argument to the lambda function, so it is only passing the value of LHS. Look at the example in [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html):

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
def f(x):
    return x**3 + x**2

derivative(func=f, x0=1.0, dx=1e-6)
4.9999999999217337
```

Here, 4.99 is the derivative of f on x=1 when moving x by 1e-6. Say that f has two variables:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x**3 + y**2
```

If you want the partial derivative with respect to y, then you'd need a wrapper function for scipy to understand which variable to change. This would look like:

```
def wrapper(y):
    return f(x, y)
```

And of course, now you need a value for x

```
x = 1
derivative(wrapper, 2)
4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit unsure about wrapper functions. Could you point me towards somewhere I could learn a bit more about them? cheers

Comment: It is just a function that will call the other function (in this context, with fewer parameters). It is equivalent to doing: derivative(lambda y: f(x, y), 2)